# Python equivalence to inline functions or macros

Tags: python, optimization, inline-functions

I just realized that doing

```
x.real*x.real+x.imag*x.imag
```

is three times faster than doing

```
abs(x)**2
```

where x is a numpy array of complex numbers. For code readability, I could define a function like

```
def abs2(x):
    return x.real*x.real+x.imag*x.imag
```

which is still far faster than abs(x)**2, but it is at the cost of a function call. Is it possible to inline such a function, as I would do in C using macro or using inline keyword?

Comment: If you need this kind of optimisations, you probably need to use something like Cython.

Comment: PyPy to the rescue!

Comment: If you care about such small optimisations, you should be using C, not python. python is not about speed, really.

Comment: Have you tried timing the statement vs. function call to see if there's really a difference?

Comment: In addition the the very correct and important (seriously, listen to them), note that due to the dynamic nature of Python, the only time inlining could possible happen is at runtime. This is one of the many optimizations PyPy does (although it doesn't have a remotely complete NumPy yet; but at least it's being worked on), and PyPy works best on idiomatic Python code, not on code written to shave off tiny bits of time off execution overhead.

Comment: @vartec: I measured the same for small arrays (100 elements).  For large arrays (10000 elments), however, he is probably right.

Comment: Obviously extracting square root is much slower than doing two multiplications and one addition.  Why not just `x*x.conj()`, by the way?

Comment: @MarkRansom Python function calls are notoriously expensive, it's the price paid for the monkey-patching capabilities of Python, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54524575/257645

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Is it possible to inline such a function, as I would do in C using macro or using inline keyword?

No. Before reaching this specific instruction, Python interpreters don't even know if there's such a function, much less what it does.

As noted in comments, PyPy **will inline automatically** (the above still holds - it "simply" generates an optimized version at runtime, benefits from it, but breaks out of it when it's invalidated), although in this specific case that doesn't help as implementing NumPy on PyPy started only shortly ago and isn't even beta level to this day. But the bottom line is: Don't worry about optimizations on this level in Python. Either the implementations optimize it themselves or they don't, it's not your responsibility.

Comment: +1 "Don't worry about optimizations on this level in Python. Either the implementations optimize it themselves or they don't, it's not your responisbility."

Comment: @phant0m Not sure why you guys like that quote so much... It basically says you cannot optimize without making code ugly. I just had to inline several calls to make my program twice as fast. At least it was worth it...

Comment: I also find it a bit hard to accept that last comment. It's nice and all that it's "not my responsibility", but at the end of the day, I can't tell my boss that it's somebody else's fault if my code misses performance targets.

Comment: If PyPy inlines automatically, does that allow it to do optimizations such as omitting to return values that will not be used by the caller, so that those variables can be destructed earlier to free up memory or perhaps not be computed at all if not needed? For some applications where the variables take up a lot of space such optimizations can be critical.

Comment: Does it really matter who's responsibility you think it is to optimize the code? What you're expressing is your opinion. The fact is that whether you choose to optimize or not comes with real consequences, both those that are beneficial and those that are not so beneficial.

Comment: I can't believe this is the most up-voted answer...  There's plenty of scope for AST transformations in Python, including something very close to what the OP asked for. The next answer is a lot better, and I'm surprised that kind of inlining isn't used more often.

Answer (score 37):

Not exactly what the OP has asked for, but close:

> [Inliner](https://github.com/orf/inliner) inlines Python function calls. Proof of concept for [this
> blog
> post](http://tomforb.es/automatically-inline-python-function-calls)
>
> ```
> from inliner import inline
>
> @inline
> def add_stuff(x, y):
>     return x + y
>
> def add_lots_of_numbers():
>     results = []
>     for i in xrange(10):
>          results.append(add_stuff(i, i+1))
> ```
>
> In the above code the add_lots_of_numbers function is converted into
> this:
>
> ```
> def add_lots_of_numbers():
>     results = []
>     for i in xrange(10):
>          results.append(i + i + 1)
> ```

Also anyone interested in this question and the complications involved in implementing such optimizer in CPython, might also want to have a look at:

- [bpo-10399: AST Optimization: inlining of function calls](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/54608)
- [PEP 511 -- API for code transformers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0511/) (Rejected)

Comment: Sorry what is the difference between your solution and the question?

Comment: @RogerS, the OP had asked about something similar to C macros (inline keyword) which are very flexible and efficient. This library has some [limitations](https://tomforb.es/automatically-inline-python-function-calls/#limitations) and has a startup time cost, but other than those, it does what the question asks.

Answer (score 10):

I'll agree with everyone else that such optimizations will just cause you pain *on CPython*, that if you care about performance you should consider PyPy (though our NumPy may be too incomplete to be useful).  However I'll disagree and say you can care about such optimizations on PyPy, not this one specifically as has been said PyPy does that automatically, but if you know PyPy well you really can tune your code to make PyPy emit the assembly you want, not that you need to almost ever.

Answer (score 9):

No.

The closest you can get to C macros is a script (awk or other) that you may include in a makefile, and which substitutes a certain pattern like abs(x)**2 in your python scripts with the long form.

Comment: ... which is a horrible idea, a lot of extra work and a decent chance of obscure breakage for nearly zero practical gain.

Comment: Python is not the fastest language there is anyway, which is ok because of its fast development cycles. Adding a "preprocessing" step for a new python project is indeed strongly discouraged.

Comment: He did not claim that this was a good idea.  Technically, he is correct.

Answer (score 7):

Actually it might be even faster to calculate, like:

```
x.real** 2+ x.imag** 2
```

Thus, the extra cost of function call will likely to diminish. Lets see:

```
In []: n= 1e4
In []: x= randn(n, 1)+ 1j* rand(n, 1)
In []: %timeit x.real* x.real+ x.imag* x.imag
10000 loops, best of 3: 100 us per loop
In []: %timeit x.real** 2+ x.imag** 2
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.9 us per loop
```

And encapsulating the calculation in a function:

```
In []: def abs2(x):
   ..:     return x.real** 2+ x.imag** 2
   ..: 
In []: %timeit abs2(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.1 us per loop
```

Anyway (as other have pointed out) this kind of micro-optimization (in order to avoid a function call) is not really productive way to write python code.

Comment: ~3us might not be a lot if you do something 100 times, or 10000. Do something a million times and you'll want to shave that

Comment: @MrMesees there is C for that

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `lambda`:

```
abs2 = lambda x : x.real*x.real+x.imag*x.imag
```

then call it by:

```
y = abs2(x)
```

Comment: Good thought but I just tried it... That **didn't improve performance at all:** `def foo(bar): return bar` vs `foo = lambda bar: bar` both execute in `57.5 nanoseconds` on my system. Measured with timeit. So lambdas are exactly like regular functions and their calls. At least on CPython 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a dynamic programming language. Luckily Python does compile to bytecode before execution. So you can inline code. For simple solutions that don't require fat external packages you can use Pythons in house functions:

```
from inspect import getsource

abs2 = lambda z : z.real * z.real + z.imag * z.imag

def loop (zz, zs):
  for z in zs:
    zz += abs2 (z)

print ( f"loop code:\n{getsource (loop)}" )

inlined = getsource (loop).replace ("abs2 (z)", getsource (abs2).split(":")[1] )

print ( f"inlined loop code:\n{inlined}" )

compiled = compile (inlined, '<string>', 'exec').co_code

def loop2 (zz, zs):
  for z in zs:
    zz += z.real * z.real + z.imag * z.imag

compiled2 = compile (getsource (loop2), '<string>', 'exec').co_code

print ( f"compiled loop  code: {compiled}" )
print ( f"compiled loop2 code: {compiled2}")
```

Note: this only supports one line lambdas with the parameters having the same name than the passed variables. A simple and very hackish solution, but Python isn't an interpreter language to not support real time code editing.