# Python dictionary creation: Dictionary comprehension vs Counter

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have been comparing the speed of dictionary creation methods in Python.

In the following example, `collections.Counter()` and the iterative approaches take the same speed (0.002 secs), whereas the dictionary comprehension method is notably slower (1.115 secs).

I have 2 questions:
1.) Why is the dictionary comprehension slower?
2.) Is there a dictionary comprehension that could match the speed of the other 2 approaches?

```
s1 = 'string'*10000

# dict comp
d1 = {x:s1.count(x) for x in s1}

# iteration
d1={}
for x in s1:
    d1[x] = d1.get(x,0)+1

# Counter
d1 = collections.Counter(s1)
```

Comment: The dictionary comprehension is O(n**2)

Comment: Also function invocation is expensive in python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893139/why-is-a-function-method-call-in-python-expensive