# how to repeat / expand expressions in python

Tags: python, inline

What is the most pythonic way to repeat an expression in Python.

**Context :** A function is getting passed a dictionary (with possibly 20 elements) and I need to extract and use values from this dictionary **if they exist**. Something like this :

```
x = dict_name['key1'] if dict_name['key1'] else ''
```

Now, instead of writing this logic 20 times for all 20 different keys, I would like to define this expression at one place and then use it repeatedly. It will be easier to maintain in future. In "C/C++" programming languages, it makes a good case of `#define` or `inline` functions. What would be Pythonic way to do this in Python?

As you would have guessed, I am novice in Python. So I appreciate your help on this or pointers to constructs for this in Python.

Comment: should this be a use case for lambda function ?

Comment: get_val = lambda key: dict_name.get(key, '')

Comment: That's what functions are for.

Comment: @shravster If you are going to assign a lambda function to a name you might as well use `def` instead.

Comment: Why would `dict_name.get('key1', '')` not suffice?

Comment: @BrenBarn : Yes , perhaps lambda function, if there are really a function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : I would have to repeat that expression 20 times and now imagine if dict_name or default value has to change tomorrow for some reason. I will have to do that change at 20 places. Which can be avoided by using lambda functions as that will require change only at one place.

Comment: @ViFI Sure, but no need for a lambda function. Just a normal function definition would work and is the standard approach. Lambda is exclusively a convenience for anonymous functions, say passing a quick, simple function as a parameter to another function. So something like `def extract(): dict_name.get('k1','')` would be the most Pythonic approach.

Answer (score 0):

Whether there is an "equivalent" to `inline` in Python depends on who you ask, and what you check.

For no equivalent, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6442497/2707864

For equivalent, e.g.: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch07s06.html

From a practical point of view, `lambda` would do the trick (`dict.get` replaces your ternary conditional operator)

```
dict_get = lambda key : dict_name.get(key, '')
```

Or you can always define a one-line function.

```
def dict_get( key ) : dict_name.get( key, '' )
```

Pythonicity is quite often (always?) subjective.

Comment: In the sense that assigning a lambda function to a name goes against [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) it is not Pythonic.